# Javascript - display hidden div from external link with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried many things from this site and cannot get my javascript to work for the life of me. Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I'm missing. I'm very new to Javascript. I'd appreciate any insight.

```js
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/ans1/") > -1) {
  document.getElementById('ans2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ans1').style.display = 'true';
} else if (url.indexOf("/ans2/") > -1) {
  document.getElementById('ans1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ans2').style.display = 'true';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-row">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="row-heading">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <ul class="faq">
      <li class="faq-item"><a href="#ans1" class="faq-item-toggle"><i   class="fa fa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>OAC FAQ 1</a>

        <div id="ans1" class="faq-item-answer"><a href="ans1">
    Answer.</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="faq-item"><a href="#ans1" class="faq-item-toggle"><i class="fa   fa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>OAC FAQ 1</a>
        <div id="ans2" class="faq-item-answer"><a href="ans2">

    Answer.
    </a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: true` is not a valid CSS rule. Use `display: block` instead.

Also, you should probably cache your DOM nodes as variables instead of repeatedly calling `getElementById`.

Lastly, you should be using `location.hash` to determine which page has been selected.

**Edit:** As [Super User has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968235/7256039), one of your anchor tags should read `href="#ans2"` instead of `href="#ans1"` as well. This HTML mistake should not affect your toggle logic, though.

```js
var hash = location.hash;
var ans1 = document.getElementById('ans1')
var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2')

if (hash === '#ans1') {
  ans2.style.display = 'none'
  ans1.style.display = 'block'
  ans1.previousElementSibling.click()
} else if (hash === '#ans2') {
  ans1.style.display = 'none'
  ans2.style.display = 'block'
  ans2.previousElementSibling.click()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-row">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="row-heading">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <ul class="faq">
      <li class="faq-item">
        <a href="#ans1" class="faq-item-toggle">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>
          OAC FAQ 1
        </a>
        <div id="ans1" class="faq-item-answer">
          <a href="ans1">Answer.</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="faq-item">
        <a href="#ans2" class="faq-item-toggle">
          <i class="fafa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>
          OAC FAQ 2
        </a>
        <div id="ans2" class="faq-item-answer">
          <a href="ans2">Answer.</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I made your updates and the ones below from @Super-user. However, when I add this to my link .org/faq-test/#ans1 it still takes me to the FAQ page but doesn't open the appropriate faq.

Comment: Hi I've made the updates to my variables in the javascript you recommended. when I have the .org/faq-test/#ans1, it has the div open automatically, but then it's not showing the actual text, it just moves the "OAC FAQ 1" title down.

Comment: Do you have more code that is providing the toggling functionality? Maybe if you compile it all into a JSFiddle and edit your question I might be able to see what is going wrong, but given only this code it's hard to reason about the problem you are describing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BAnn/0nzsjqsy/ - here is some external js for the faq. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I edited my code above slightly; try it and let me know if it works. I still can't tell where the code you posted originally fits into your JSFiddle, though.

Comment: I have it all on content block in Wordpress - https://jsfiddle.net/tedhp3ar/ like so. The javascript is with the HTML. The JSFiddle that I Have linked here is exactly how I have it in my content block on my WordPress page.

Answer (score 1):

In both link you have passed `#ans1` reference, you should pass `#ans2` in second link.
Also you have to set `display: block` property for javascript

```js
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/ans1/") > -1) {
  document.getElementById('ans2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ans1').style.display = 'block';
} else if (url.indexOf("/ans2/") > -1) {
  document.getElementById('ans1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ans2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-row">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="row-heading">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <ul class="faq">
      <li class="faq-item"><a href="#ans1" class="faq-item-toggle"><i   class="fa fa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>OAC FAQ 1</a>

        <div id="ans1" class="faq-item-answer"><a href="ans1">
    Answer.</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="faq-item"><a href="#ans2" class="faq-item-toggle"><i class="fa   fa-angle-down faq-toggle-arrow"></i>OAC FAQ 1</a>
        <div id="ans2" class="faq-item-answer"><a href="ans2">

    Answer.
    </a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I made updates from you and @gyre. However, when I add this to my link .org/faq-test/#ans1 it still takes me to the FAQ page but doesn't open the appropriate faq.